# Entity Framework (v6) Eager-Loading weird behaviour - 'Gotcha'

Tags: entity-framework-6, eager-loading, navigation-properties

Should the following two queries be equivalent?
(note the placement of .Include)

== (V1)

```
using (var ctx = new Entities()) {

    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; //return stronglyTyped Entity, not dynamic entity...

    IQueryable<TB_MyHeader> query = from hd in ctx.TB_MyHeader.Include(h => h.TB_MyLines)
        join wo in ctx.TB_AnotherTable on hd.fkId equals wo.ID
        where wo.woPk == @id
    orderby hd.PoItem
    select hd;

    var headerPlusLines = query
        .AsNoTracking() 
        .ToList();

    return headerPlusLines;
}
```

== (V2)

```
using (var ctx = new Entities()) {

    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; //return stronglyTyped Entity, not dynamic entity...

    IQueryable<TB_MyHeader> query = (from hd in ctx.TB_MyHeader
        join wo in ctx.TB_AnotherTable on hd.fkId equals wo.ID
    where wo.woPk == @id
    orderby hd.PoItem
    select hd)
    .Include(h => h.TB_MyLines);


    var headerPlusLines = query
        .AsNoTracking() 
        .ToList();

    return headerPlusLines;
}
```

The first version (V1) may not fetch children into the Nav property, depending on combinations of how ProxyCreationEnabled, LazyLoadingEnabled are set true/false.

In fact, the opposite of expected result occurs; if i set LazyLoadingEnabled = false, no children load at all;
When i would have expect it to 'dont be lazy, load it now !'

Whats going on?

Comment: Have you had a look at the SQL that Entity Framework generates for both versions? That could shed some light on the different behaviour...

Comment: @Alistair good point.. will look at the gen sql when i get the time (I've forgotten how to do it, any tips?)

Comment: Add this line above the `query` definition to see the logs generated by Entity Framework, including the generated SQL for your queries: `ctx.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);`. When you run in debug mode you should see the logs come through in the Output window.

Comment: Thanks: saved me hours on remembering how i did it previously :-)